# Python, Matching list elements with a dictionary containing list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, tf-idf

I have a dictionary containing dates and a sequence of term frequency shown below:

```
{
    'Wed Aug 09': [('夏', 49), ('日本', 48), ('海', 39), ('', 33), ('日', 28), ('写真', 25), ('まし', 24), ('', 24), ('️', 23), (' ソフトクリーム', 22)],
    'Thu Aug 10': [('夏', 1010), ('日本', 672), ('暑い', 501), ('海', 379), ('型', 253), ('日', 242), ('人', 223), ('まし', 209), ('い い', 159), ('雨', 149)]
}
```

Out of all these terms I have a list of keywords for which I want to summarize all data:

```
key_words = ["夏", "海", "暑い", "雨", "秋", "寒い", "台風", "冬"]
```

I want my output to look like:

```
{
    'Wed Aug 09': [('夏', 49), ('海', 39),('暑い', 34), ('雨', 26), ('秋', 23), ('寒い', 15), ('台風', 12), ('冬', 9) ],
    # ...
}
```

This basically extracts the keywords from the dictionary with the list of tuples.

My code for extracting looks like this:

```
result = dict()
for key, value in date_words.items():
    if key_words in date_words[value]:
        result[key] = value
 print(result)
```

But it returns an empty dict. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: what is `Wed Aug 09 `? Where does `('冬', 9)` come from? Unclear, voting to close

Comment: Why does your expected output include `('暑い', 34), ('雨', 26), ('秋', 23), ('寒い', 15), ('台風', 12), ('冬', 9)`? Your input data and expected output don't seem to match.

Comment: The output I have jut randomly picked numbers. The all idea is to build a visualization with the required keywords, the input data is the tf-idf of all tweets retrieved on that date. So after computing the tf-idf I want to represent in a life streaming graph the results of the term-frequency of each keyword. Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking if there is a *single list object* with the same strings in your value. There is not, there are tuples there with each two elements. You'll need to test for the intersection instead.

I'd make `key_words` a *set* instead:

```
key_words = {"夏", "海", "暑い", "雨", "秋", "寒い", "台風", "冬"}  # use set([....]) in Python 2
```

and use a list comprehension to extract all matching tuples:

```
result = {}
for key, value in date_words.items():
    result[key] = [(k, v) for k, v in value if k in key_words]
```

That can be further combined into a dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {key: [(k, v) for k, v in value if k in key_words]
          for key, value in date_words.items()}
```